# Что именно пытается сделать данный код?

Tags: mysql, защита, sql-injection

В логах ошибок появилось очень много строк с sql запросом - просто не сомневаюсь что пытаются навредить...
Но не совсем понимаю чем именно хотят навредить!

Дело в том что кука хранит ключ массива, а при запросе массива - выходит ошибка, видать злоумышленник в куку подставляет свое значение и запрашивает страницу по 15 раз в секунду.

Вот несколько вариантов тех данных что пытаются подменить:

```
1\\' AND (SELECT 0x716b6157)=0x716b6157 AND \\'kDyY\\'=\\'kDyY

1\\' AND ORD(MID((SELECT DISTINCT(IFNULL(CAST(schema_name AS CHAR),0x20)) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA LIMIT 5,1),3,1))>120 AND \\'sJTm\\'=\\'sJTm

1\\' OR (SELECT * FROM (SELECT(SLEEP(0)))HZuZ) AND \\'aSiG\\'=\\'aSiG

1\\' AND 42=86 AND \\'OQmB\\'=\\'OQmB
```

Чем мне грозит - когда вредитель все таки загрузит свою инъекцию?
И что именно делает подобный код?

Comment: Видимо что то прощупывают. вы лучше код поправьте через который это происходит

Comment: @Mike а как же подправить если не знаю что ищут. На данный момент добавил условия для проверки этой переменной на нужные числа.

Comment: Так это не имеет значения. главное что бы все входящие извне данные проверялись на допустимость перед использованием. А в идеале надо бы запросы в БД все делать только с использованием привязываемых переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php тогда подобные атаки в принципе будут невозможны